# I cannot compile gtk apps after updating to 18.04

Tags: command-line, compiling, gtk, c, glade

I am trying to compile a program with a user interface as a .out file. I compiled it just the same way before and I did not edit the code, using this

```
`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

Back in 16.04, the code compiled into an application and I could double click and launch the app. This time, I can't. When I double click, it tries to open with glade and shows an error. For some reason, the compiler or the system thinks the file is supposed to be a shared library. How can I tell it to be an application? I have to execute it in the terminal like a non-gtk compiled C file.

How can I compile it as an app on 18.04?

Comment: As of gcc-6.2 gcc is configured with the `--enable-default-pie` option, that's why it's a shared object. This shouldn't normally prevent executing the file. (take a look in /usr/bin) I guess you could try using the respective compile & link options of `-fno-pie -no-pie`

Comment: @doug consider to write your method as answer. Really `gcc hello.c \`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0\` -no-pie` allows *a.out* to be executable from file-manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of gcc-6.2 gcc in Ubuntu is configured with the --enable-default-pie option, (Position Independent Executable),  that's why it's a shared object. (- LSB shared object

The compiler override for this is `-fno-pie` , the linker override  is `-no-pie`

Apparently for an a.out file you only need to apply the linker -no-pie  though both options together  also work.

Also a factor may be your file manager, some will allow marking & running the shared object as exectubale. Nautilus doesn't anymore.(nemo does